# Java Swing GUI in other classes

Tags: java, swing, oop

I'm currently working on my first Swing project in Java. I want to split my GUI into 3 seperate classes. My main class, `TicTacToeGUI`, and two others: `MenuBar` and `Board`.

I have a problem with my menu. I can't figure out how to make it visible. The code is compiling but the menu is not showing.

**TicTacToeGUI:**

```
package TicTacToee;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import java.awt.*;

public class TicTacToeGUI {

    public TicTacToeGUI() {
        super();
        Board board = new Board();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    TicTacToeGUI window = new TicTacToeGUI();
                    //window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Board:**

```
package TicTacToee;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import java.awt.*;

public class Board {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JButton[][] board;

    public Board(){
        initializeBoard();
    }

    public void initializeBoard() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Tic Tac Toe v0.1");
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 600, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        frame.setResizable(false);
        //Creating MENU
        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        //JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        //panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 2));
        //frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        //panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3, 2, 2));


        //board = new JButton[3][3];
    }
}
```

**MenuBar:**

```
package TicTacToee;

import javax.swing.*;

public class MenuBar extends JMenuBar {

    private JMenuBar menuBar;
    private JMenu menu;
    private JMenuItem newGame;
    private JMenuItem quit;

    public MenuBar(){
        initializeMenuBar();
    }

    public void initializeMenuBar() {
        //Create menu Bar
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        menu = new JMenu("MENU");
        menuBar.add(menu);

        newGame = new JMenuItem();
        menu.add(newGame);
    }
}
```

Comment: `window.setJMenuBar(new MenuBar())`??

Comment: Im a little confused why you extend JMenuBar, but then in the Class you create another JMenuBar object? You need to use “this” instead of calling a new JMenuBar in the MenuBar class.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You aren’t extending `JMenuBar` correctly. Try something like this:

```
public void initializeMenuBar(){

    menu = new JMenu("MENU");
    this.add(menu);

    newGame = new JMenuItem();
    menu.add(newGame);

}
```

or maybe

```
public void initializeMenuBar(){
    //Create menu Bar
    menuBar = new JMenuBar();

    menu = new JMenu("MENU");
    menuBar.add(menu);

    newGame = new JMenuItem();
    menu.add(newGame);

    this = menuBar;

}
```

Comment: I think the question is why extend `JMenuBar` at all?  I've never needed to extend it.  Just use it as is and call `.add()` to add menu items. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html

Comment: @markspace That’s what I’D normally do too, but he said he intentionally wanted it separated into three classes so I obliged.

Comment: *"he said he intentionally wanted it separated into three classes"* The menu bar logic might be in another class without extending it. *"so I obliged."* See [Is “Don't do it” a valid answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/is-dont-do-it-a-valid-answer)

Comment: @AndrewThompson the thing is, it’s not a “don’t do it” scenario. Extending a JMenuBar can be a valid solution, it’s not going to kill his code. That the great part about software engineering, you can do it however you want as long as it works and (preferably) other people can understand it.

Comment: Thanks for a quick respond. Your idea to use "this" is working. Actually i think i will rebuild my code to main class and gui class(with board and menu).